# Need to add a row based off criteria from another column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, duplicates, fillna

I need to add a row in my df with certain text based off criteria from another column. Depending on the column criteria, then a row will be added under that certain row.

```
ID     Name      Order    Children   Pet  
12     Joe       Parent     yes      dog
13     Mary      Parent     yes      cat
14     Paul      Parent     yes      dog
15     Emma      Parent     yes      cat
```

In my example dataframe, I would want to transform the data and insert rows if a parent has a child and if a parent has a pet (dogs only for this case). I would want the following end result.

```
ID     Name         Order    Children   Pet  
12     Parent; Joe  Parent     yes      dog
12     Child; Joe
12     Dog; Joe
13     Parent; Mary Parent     yes      cat
13     Child; Mary
14     Parent; Paul Parent     yes      dog
14     Child; Paul
14     Dog; Paul
15     Parent; Emma Parent     yes      cat
15     Child; Emma
```

To add the prefix

```
df['Name'] = 'Parent; ' + df['Name'].astype(str)
```

After that, I've tried duplicating the df and then stacking the df's - it works but it's an exhausting method. So I'd like to have an if statement instead.
If Child == 'yes', add row below appropriate parent that reads 'Child;' + parent name.
Then another if for if Pet == 'dog', add row below child that reads 'Dog; ' + parent name.

I will use a df.drop later to remove the order, children and pet columns.

Comment: Do you only want to keep the column `Name` after, that's it ?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this works for you or you need your data model to be different ?

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
##Create Dataframe
cols = ['Name', 'Order', 'Children', 'Pet']  
data = [['Joe', 'Parent', 'yes', 'dog'],
        ['Mary', 'Parent', 'yes', 'cat'],
        ['Paul', 'Parent', 'yes', 'dog'],
        ['Emma', 'Parent', 'yes', 'cat']
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

## Split in as many group as we want
Parent = 'Parent; ' + df['Name']
Child = 'Child ; ' + df.loc[df['Children']=='yes', 'Name']
Dog = 'Dog ; ' + df.loc[df['Pet']=='dog', 'Name']
## Concatenate them
df_final = pd.concat([Parent, Child, Dog])
df_final.to_frame().sort_index()

Out [1]:
    Name
0   Parent; Joe
0   Child ; Joe
0   Dog ; Joe
1   Parent; Mary
1   Child ; Mary
2   Parent; Paul
2   Child ; Paul
2   Dog ; Paul
3   Parent; Emma
3   Child ; Emma
```